# Appcompat activity required as argument for function used in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-appcompat

I am using an external library in my app. The first argument used in the example is "this". Which refers to an appcompat activity. However I am using this in a fragment shich obviously doesn't extend appcompat activity.

This is the library:

https://github.com/TouchBoarder/weekdays-buttons-bar

I am not sure whether there is anything I can do. Can I extend the fragment to something compatible (right now it just extends fragment).

Below is a screenshot of the issue:

[image]

EDIT:

This is what I extend in my MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
```

The Fragment that is called innside Main activity is extended like this:

```
public class AddAlarmFragment extends Fragment {
```

And I am trying to create the data source in the oncreate method of the fragment like this:

```
   @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       // Inflate the layout for this fragment
       View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add_alarm, container, false);


        WeekdaysDataSource wds = new WeekdaysDataSource(, R.id.weekdays_stub)
                .start(this);



        new WeekdaysDataSource.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onWeekdaysItemClicked(int attachId,WeekdaysDataItem item) {
                // Do something if today is selected?
                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                if(item.getCalendarDayId()==calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)&&item.isSelected())
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Carpe diem",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onWeekdaysSelected(int attachId,ArrayList<WeekdaysDataItem> items) {
                //Filter on the attached id if there is multiple weekdays data sources
                if(attachId==R.id.weekdays_stub){
                    // Do something on week 4?
                }
            }

        };
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: try YourActivity.this instead of this

Comment: Hi Vishal thanks, unfortunately doesn't work.

Comment: your activity extends which Activity?

Comment: Activity or AppCompactActivity ?

Comment: The fragment is inside Main Activity which extends app compat. I tried. MainActivity.this and getActivity().this. Neither work. I am trying to open it inside the fragment.

Comment: did you try using `getActivity()` instead of this?

Comment: @Aman yes this is the first thing I tried.

Comment: try getActivity() instead of this @NicholasMuir

Comment: @VishalPatoliya please see my response to Aman above. I tried that before posting here.

Comment: so what ? @NicholasMuir

Comment: @VishalPatoliya I do not understand your question. I tried it before I posted. That does not work it says android.support.v4.FragmentActivity in place of the error shown in the picture above.

Comment: You are probably downvoted for no code...

Comment: @cricket_007 Fair enough, kind of makes sense.

Comment: At least show the definition of your Fragment class, and which `Fragment`  is in your imports. Then, it might also be useful to mention what library you are trying to use, so we might go search the examples ourselves

Comment: @cricket_007 thanks for the advice have edited my question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you tried casting `getActivity()`?

```
((AppCompatActivity) getActivity(), R.id.weekdays_stub)
```

Read the Android API, you can see AppCompatActivity does extend FragmentActivity and `getActivity()` does return a FragmentActivity, not an AppCompatActivity, as expected by your library.

I do find it odd that a AppCompatActivity is even the defined parameter rather than a Context

Comment: @criket Thanks very much! Solved it. That is the first time I have seen anything like that. Appreciate the help

Comment: No problem. Just one of those Java polymorphism quirks that can be confusing at times